# Use delegate (predicate) in EF Core 5.x throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I 've got a simple query but it throws, that it couldn't be translated

here is the function

```
    public async Task<Voucher> Get(Predicate<Voucher> predicate)
    {
        try
        {
           var voucher = await _promotionCoreContext.Vouchers.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => predicate(i));
           return voucher;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

usage is something like this:

```
repository.Get(c => c.Code == "abc");
```

but for a reason it can't translate the predicate, it compiles though.

> ---- System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(v => Invoke(__predicate_0, v)
> )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by
> inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

The Packages I use atm.

[image]

Anyone know how I can fix this without making it client side with ToList()

Comment: Problem is your predicate. It should be `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IQueryable.FirstOrDefaultAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.firstordefaultasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) takes an `Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>`, not a `Func<TSource,bool>`.  The [Enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0) extension methods can work with `Func<TSource,bool>`, but since that's basically a function pointer, EF can't translate it to SQL.